# How to reset the bsDatepicker input?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript, datepicker

I used a bootstrap Datepicker in my Angular 7 project.
I put it as an input inside a form like this:

I want to clear all the form once a "clear" button is clicked. The form.reset() function didn't work with the datepicker input.

```
 <div class="col-lg-8 form-group">
          <input id="startDate" type="text" placeholder="From" 
          class="form-control" bsDatepicker
          [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true, dateInputFormat:'YYYY- 
          MM-DD'}" [(ngModel)]="selectedStartDate"
            (ngModelChange)="updateMyStartDate($event)" [ngModelOptions]=" 
          {standalone: true}">
 </div>
```

Do you have any idea what should I do to reset the datepicker input and empty them .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reset input/ngModel value on clear button click.

Put below line after `form.reset();` in your function

`this.selectedStartDate.value = ' ';`

(for example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nv5qts?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts)